# How to add a column to the table from another table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I have 2 tables :

1. `Person.Person`
2. `Person.PersonPhone`

The table `Person.PersonPhone` contains 4 columns :

```
BusinessEntityID
PhoneNumber
PhoneNumberTypeId
ModifiedDate
```

The first table contains more columns but I'm working only with 4 :

```
 FirstName, LastName, PersonType, BusinesEntityID
```

So, I want to add to my first table (`Person.Person`) column `PhoneNumber` from `Person.PersonPhone`. And here I encountered the difficulty.

This is what I did

```
USE AdventureWorks2019

SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonType, BusinessEntityID
FROM Person.Person
WHERE PersonType = 'EM '

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM Person.PersonPhone
WHERE PhoneNumberTypeID = 3
```

And this is my initial condition: check the content of `Person.Person`, `Person.PersonPhone` and `Person.PhoneNumberType` tables from  AdventureWorks2019 database.

Write a query that shows each person's First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, but only for the records with "Employee" Person Type and "Work" Phone Type (please do not "hardcode" the phone type, use subquery or join instead)

Comment: Are the tables related by the `BusinessEntityID` field?

Comment: You need to review your class materials (or any of many online tutorials) on the basics of writing SQL joins and/or subqueries. Next, attempt to update your queries based on what you have learned. If you continue to have issues once you have done that, update your question with your progress and we will be more likely able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query code, and it took like 8 seconds for the phone number list to show up.  I thought that was kind of odd, but the SQL app did it.

```
USE AdventureWorks2019

SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonType, BusinessEntityID
FROM Person.Person
WHERE PersonType = 'EM '

SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM Person.PersonPhone
WHERE PhoneNumberTypeID = 3
```